# _In_ in function documentation

Tags: c++, msdn

I'm trying to write documentation to my library and was looking for function declaration sample. Found in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376723(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
DWORD RasClearLinkStatistics(
  _In_ HRASCONN hRasConn,
  _In_ DWORD    dwSubEntry
);
```

Format looks nice, but what mens mark `_In_`  in this function? Is it standart C++?

Comment: You are looking at Microsoft source-code annotation language (SAL) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916383.aspx

Comment: So, I suppose this is not god style in case my function will be used in Linux